# How can I stop completed job pods to be restarted after scale down

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

I’m executing k8s indexed job with completions=30, parallelism=30 on azure kubernetes service. Its pods have big memory request so need one node for each pod. When I deployed the job, scale up of nodes happen. Some pods complete fastly. After completion of these pods, scale down of nodes happen, then completed pods are evicted and restarted on another node, **although they are completed already**. How can I stop this behaviour? Setting pod disruption budget or `"cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false"` was not successful.

Cluster information:

- Kubernetes version: 1.24.3
- Cloud being used: azure kubernetes service
- Installation method: Helm
- Host OS: Linux

Answer (score 1):

This behavior of Kubernetes is down to the Kubernetes JobTracker relying on completed Pods to not be removed in order to track the Job completion status. See the [Kubernetes Enhancement Proposal (KEP-2307)](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-apps/2307-job-tracking-without-lingering-pods) for more details.

What happens on the scale down of nodes, then completed pods are evicted, but the JobTracker relies on the existence of this Pod to derive the Job Completions status, viz Pods Statuses:  4 Running / 2 Succeeded / 0 Failed. After the pods are killed on a scale down, At the next JobSync the index completion get's reset back and all the Pods killed for the index are restarted.

Setting pod disruption budget or "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false" does not help as these pods are successful and marked ready for garbage collection. These are not used by the ClusterAutoScaler for auto-scaling decisions.

The fix is to turn on the feature gate [JobTrackingWithFinalizers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/#:%7E:text=Feature%20gates%20are%20a%20set,flag%20on%20each%20Kubernetes%20component) or upgrade to version 1.26 or later where this is the default. This enhancement removes the dependency on Pods being around for Job completion tracking. The Job controller creates Pods with a finalizer to prevent finished Pods from being removed by the garbage collector. The Job controller removes the finalizer from the finished Pods once it has accounted for them. It does this by keeping an additional state in the Job object. In subsequent Job syncs, the controller ignores finished Pods that don't have the finalizer

Follow the change tracking in this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/108887)